# Why am I getting a '404 Not Found' when sending a JQuery $.ajax() request to a named route from my JS script in /public/js/ directory?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, routes

This is my first Laravel (v6) app. I am trying to send an AJAX request to server on button click by user. So, I am following [this example](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-ajax-request-exampleexample.html). In this example, the have used the **`route()`** helper function to generate and access a named route from AJAX request from a JQuery script *defined within their `blade.php` file.*

When I do it in exactly the same way, i.e. define my $.ajax() within my `blade.php` view, it works fine.

However, my JS functions are defined in a `scripts.js` file in `/public/js/` directory. So naturally, I want to send my AJAX request to my controller from this `scripts.js` file. But when I try to send the ditto same `$.ajax()` request from this `scripts.js`, I get **`POST http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20route('ajaxRequest.post')%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`**.

So the only explanation in my mind is that the `/routes/web.php` file where the named route is defined, must not be accessible from the `/public/js/` directory, or the Controller where that function is defined must not be accessible from `/public/js` directory. **Is it true? What should I do about it?**

---

**CODE:-**

**1. In my routes/web.php:**

```
Route::get('/insertData', 'JonnaController@getDataInsertionFormView');
Route::post('/insertData', 'JonnaController@ajaxRequestPost')->name('ajaxRequest.post');
```

**2. In my JonnaController.php:**

```
public function ajaxRequestPost(Request $request) {         
        $input = $request->all();
        \Log::info($input);    
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']);
}
```

**3. In  of my blade.php:**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

**4. In my public/js/scripts.js:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
...
$.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:"{{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}",
       data:{titleUserInput: titleUserInput},
       success:function(data){
          alert(data.success);
          console.log(data);
       }
    });
```

Comment: php does not run in a  js file so the url it is trying to access is the exact string value of the $.ajax `url` without ever being compiled

Comment: In your blade page view you could create  a script tag and write the php `route()` to a javascript variable there and use that variable for `url` in the js file

Comment: @charlietfl I have done something along those lines, as reflected in my answer below. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have implemented a hacky solution. In my `blade.php` view, I have defined a hidden input type element with `value={{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}` and then accessed this hidden input element's `value` attribute from my JS script, and used it as value of my `url` in my $.ajax() request. This works.

Comment: Cleaner would be `<script> var ajaxUrl = "{{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}";</script>` ... then in js file `url: ajaxUrl,`

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah thanks. I am returning to programming after long and I realise how dumb I have become.

Comment: No worries. There are old frameworks and full sites I used to work with and now when I return go through lots of head scratching sometimes. Part of the game I guess

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for encouragement =)